# Change the privileges system and rep display to a timed ranking

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges

I wanted to throw these 2 ideas out there though guessing they won't be popular ideas.

1. Age the privileges

   As it is, someone with lots of points but who has not been active on the site in years is grandfathered into all their privileges. It feels like those privileges should age to me. I might have answered C++ questions for 20k points from 2008 to 2012 but arguably if I stopped contributing, those 20k points from > 8yrs ago don't suggest that I'm still knowledgeable about C++ in 2020. It's like if I quit a job, I can't come by the office and let myself in and start doing things on that company's equipment. My privileges are only valid if I kept exercising them and further, my knowledge of the company itself will be out of date, like maybe they switched from mostly email to mostly slack, or from one vcs to another, people changed, etc...
2. Display users yearly contribution rank, not their points.

   Would it be more useful to display year to date contribution ranking instead of points everywhere points are displayed now. It seems like the fact that one user has 100k points from 10yrs ago is less useful info than another user has 10k points from this year.

Probably, for privileges, the number of points need to gain one would have to change. As it is it can take years to earn one in a certain tag. On the other hand, maybe that's as it should be. Someone concentrating on a certain tag should have the privileges where as someone that gets few points a year for that same tag probably doesn't really deserve the privileges. They're getting it by attrition not merit.

I have a feeling many users will be threatened by the above ideas. Who wants to contribute a bunch and then have their "rewards" taken away if they stop. Yet I think most things in real world follow the pattern of nothing lasts forever. Certifications expire, licenses expire, knowledge goes out of date, etc..

Would S.O. be better if it emphasized the currently active contributors? Doesn't it make sense that users who haven't been on the site in years should not still have the keys to the community?

Comment: If people with high rep and therefore most/all privileges who have been on SO for many years but are no longer active, does it hurt if they still keep the privileges? And if they no longer ask/answer questions but use their privileges to help moderate SO, why should their privileges be taken away from them? Wouldn't that hurt SO? In general, what problems do your suggestions solve and how?

Comment: " don't suggest that I'm still knowledgeable about C++ in 2020" - Contra-position: I answered one Python question (IIRC) giving me a tag score of -1. That doesn't make me bad at Python - just means I don't answer Python questions. Answering ability in general isn't representative of skill. You can get 10k reputation in 50-60 days by answering mostly trash (... and that has happened recently too). Rep is called "a very rough measurement of trust" for a reason - it's not a showcase of skill or technical ability

Comment: What is a key I currently have in my possession that you want to have?

Comment: So you have been a member for a little over 3 months but haven't answered anything in the last 2 1/2 months. That's a very significant percentage of the duration of your membership. Should you not also be penalized accordingly? Since your contributions so far are very minimal why would you want to penalize those who have already contributed significantly?

Comment: The privileges are not my problem, the voters that keep upvoting that old crap from 2010 need to be banned. What good can it be that I get an upvote earlier this year for an answer I wrote [8 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11830975/578411). I've aged pretty well but some visitors and voters didn't move on, obviously.

Comment: Some users can't help that 12 years after they posted something voters still find it so relevant that it is worth an upvote today: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1293996/how-does-my-reputation-age-aka-what-old-answers-give-me-rep-way-after-it-was-po?UserId=22656

Comment: Now, when we can discuss converting some of my rep into cold hard cash, or even beer and pizza, then I'm willing to hold a discussion on the matter

Comment: @rene The site expects users to utilize existing Q&A rather than repeating a question and we close questions as duplicates when they don't. Upvoting old posts seems to be the site working as designed.

Comment: @BSMP *the site working as designed* .... recent posts on Meta make me belief not everyone agrees with that, including this OP ....

Comment: @JeanneDark, some privileges are tag specific. I agree with you that privileges such as commenting, downvoting, shouldn't age. But a tag specific privileges seem different. That you knew Swift 1.0 doesn't mean you know Swift 5.0 so whatever tag specific privileges you got for swift back when it was 1.0 doesn't seem like it qualifies you to exercise those same privileges on modern swift.

Answer (score 25):

Privileges are for the most part about moderating the site once you get beyond a couple of hundred rep. I.e. you get abilities such as editing, closing/reopening and deletion of posts.

If I leave the site for a while, maybe my programming skills have decayed or maybe they haven't. I could easily have gained brand new skills during that time. What I won't have lost though, short of some medical problem is the knowledge of when it's appropriate to edit, close or delete things because you don't really need to be a subject matter expert to do those things. You just need to have spent enough time on the site to know how things work and when it is or isn't appropriate to do things.

Comment: I feel like possibly you ignored my examples. I agree with you that privileges like being able to comment or downvote fit the current system. We can trust you to downvote or comment appropriately. But some privileges are tag related so your rep in specific tag suggests being knowledgeable on that particular tag's topic. If you haven't been around for years then we have no proof you're still knowledgeable on that topic and you should arguably not have tag specific privileges.

Comment: There is only one tag privilege, that is to close as a duplicate. You'd need to provide evidence that there was a problem with it in such circumstances.

Answer (score 8):

The reputation and privileges that one earn in stackoverflow is primarily because one have helped the community by positive contribution. There should be no reason to take those away other than the scenario when one's contributions are negative.

One's knowledge of a technology could become obsolete in future but one's contributions on that technology still could be helpful to others thereby providing value to the community.

*It's not about one, it's about one's contributions*. So it should not matter whether someone is active or not for sometime.

Comparing with a Job does not make sense to me because unlike Job there is no monetary benefit involved for contributing and moderating in stackoverflow.

Comment: *[Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance) (the last section - scroll down)