# How we could determine a better criteria to calculate reputation of users?

Tags: discussion, reputation

So far, we have upvotes/downvotes to calculate reputation of users. By the given docs of Stack Overflow, upvotes/downvotes are a score that the community gives users to appreciate their contribution.

But by my understanding, it could be a hard way, simple to implement, hard to keep it safe and pure. Some users were/are/will be greedy to collect reps. It seems that the design of the system makes users greedy to collect reputation.

And it is not the only issue. Assume a user that answered a very basic critical question many years ago and then they stopped being active for a long time. But because of answering that very basic question they collect tons of reps. Now, alongside this user assume another user that tried to be active and answers many questions (mistakes, configs, how to use...) and receives just one or two upvotes for them and in the end the second user has less reps than the first.

Which one is more active? Which one is more helpful and useful for our community? Obviously the second user.

**Solution**: If we have a complicated mathematical/statistical system to count hours of being active, number of answers with upvotes (vote could be weight of each matrix) and totally we calculate of average these matrices to grab the real reputation of users it could be better.

It will avoid users to only collect reps and make eagerness for users to be active to help others, even the management could be very simple, there is no need to spend much time and energy for care about users, because the reputation is based on several criteria.

Comment: for 99.999% of users, the solution will result in the same outcome. the users with privilege's to do stuff will still have privilege's to do stuff, and the ones without will still be without. What would this solve? If anything it may hurt answering rates.

Comment: What is the problem being solved here? People who want rep for the sake of rep will...still do the same. Having a complex mathematical formula will not dissuade them.

Comment: @AmerllicA Without gamification, would the site exist as it does today? Would it have a strong userbase? or would it just be like any other old-style forum with aging content and no new users or reason to improve yourself.

Comment: "it could help us" is... very intangible. Do you have a legit new calculation to suggest, HOW it would work? The impact it would have, and *how* it would change the community for the better? This.... lacks details I find :/. It's a "if we did things differently, it'll be better".... but without any idea of "differently", or "better"...

Comment: Possible dupe? [Change the privileges system and rep display to a timed ranking](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401163/2821954) which is a dupe of [Should reputation points be calculated via a sliding time window?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308203/2821954) which is a dupe of [Advantage to Old Users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254964/2821954) which is a dupe of [Reputation limit per question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320929/2821954) which is a dupe of [Are reputation points working as intended?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/259887/2821954)

Comment: @Patrice, yes you right, I should investigate about criteria and bring more detail, for example, prepare a mathematical function as a good proposal. thanks.

Comment: No, don't bother with the mathematical function.  Interaction with the site is elastic and has no material expectation of it being permanent (e.g. you don't have to be logged in to see answers, and I think that there are some limited things that anonymous users can do too).  Trying to calculate rep without knowing exactly how people interact or how people engage with the site is premature at best.

Comment: Listen, I don't think many people here believe the current system is not deeply flawed (at least I hope so), but we probably heard everything there is to say a thousand times and by now this is tiring even to me (not to mention those who are here for a decade). You have all the tools at your disposal: SEDE, data dumps, old discussions. If you come up with something groundbreaking then sure, but now it just feels like going in circles. P.s. A personal opinion: don't underestimate peoples' abilities to circumvent or break anything you can throw [couldn't live with the shame of a typo] at them...

Comment: reputation ceases to be something that is in any way rewarding at 20k rep. anyone pushing past that is doing it for reasons other than just gaining rep, whether they realize it or not.

Comment: if you started your business in 1990 you will for sure have more money than someone who just start right now (even with a better idea ). What I understand for your question is that you simply want to earn more Rep faster and you are asking yourself *Why didn't I create my account 8 years ago ??*

Comment: *"Which one is more helpful and useful for our community? Obviously the second user."* ... obviously? Isn't it more obvious that the first one is more helpful, because their content received that many upvotes? Or do you want to say that quantity is better than quality?

Comment: @OlegValter, please write politely

Comment: @TemaniAfif, Dear Afif, it is not related to day of registration, or my regrets, Please pay attention, both users, even second one should spend much time to earn reputation. What is different here, is activity, the send user is more active, obviously he/she is more useful

Comment: @Tom, We cannot say quality is better than quantity or not. how you assume which one has quality and which one has quantity, by my assumption the second user has both, He/She started late but answered many questions And satisfied many users

Comment: @AmerllicA - I do? Not sure where you got this from. The comment section is character limited, so I prefer to forgo the unnecessary pleasantries as much as possible (if not for the typo and subsequent reposting of the comment, I would forgo the note as well)

Comment: I created my account one year after yours, I am more active so I am earning more reputation than you .. the system is already working as it should be. The more active you are the more reputation your earn.

Comment: and honestly, if you are here only for the reputation (I remember all your old meta about bounties and fraud, etc) then you are wasting your time IMO. Reputation is a number that will never reflect any of your quality content. I know users having 2000 Rep and only 10 answers that are better than other user with million Rep and 1000+ answers. You can write 100 answers saying *try this* and *simply remove the /* while I am writing this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734530/8620333 .. you will earn more Rep but I beat you on the quality, content, SEO, etc

Comment: @AmerllicA Why do you assume the second user satisfied many users when their posts don't receive upvotes?

Comment: @Tom, the second user tried to answer many user's questions, either get the tick, upvote neither didn't get, this is a matter, he tried to help people several times.

Comment: And if those post don't get upvotes or even an accept mark, then those aren't so helpful as other post which do get both.

Comment: Surely there could be a lot of ways to make the rep system better. For example, the upvote of the high-rep users could worth more, resulting an eigenvalue calculation and a much better reputation evaluation. The problem is that any better rep calculation would be also more complex, and 1) the company behavior is that they are strongly against any modifications 2) they have clearly problems with complexity. You can see, practically all their rules are on the level of `if (X > hardcodedConst) { ..} else {..}`. We could talk about, why is it so. It is partially because money.

Comment: You think that the CEO is thinking every day on such things, how could the review/rep/voting system be made better? No! He has only superficial idea, roughly like a rep 300 user, how this works. It is nothing for him. What is important for him, that is their yearly budget. And the $ expectations of the Board. They get money from: 1) investors (they are now in the board and want their $ back, furthermore they have even lesser idea how the system works) 2) ads (here the problem is that we do not buy here anything and we have good adblockers). And others do not see the site 3) job SE 4) teams.

Comment: Result: 1) Only SO matters for the company, the other stackexchange sites are for them a money swallowing black hole. I would not be surprised if they would simply sell them. 2) You can not expect any significant change on the Q&A. I am not sure, but probably they have not even a single developer in their company HQ. 3) Instead, what they do: they are working hardly to talk with the customers on the Job SE / Teams. 4) Possibly they might also sell data, but not so darkly because it would be risky. 4) They are working hardly to get advertisers.

Comment: Note, a quick glassdoor.com query clearly shows that the SE pays very well for their developers, even on the USA customs. So they are not so bad, they have actually enough $ - they are only ignoring us because they still want to have so many.

Comment: Well, I actually did not see a single ad on the sites since years. But it is because firefox adblocking is so good that I can safely forget that it exists. If I rarely see some ad, these are always microsoft azure ads. The obvious conception is in the background: actually MS pays the company. Not because so they could sell more Azure VPS. They are doing it because the SE is a microsoft-oriented company, and supporting them makes also supporting .net and azure. But the MS probably does not get back their invested money directly. They can also track the visitors and play google with the data.

Comment: So, there is enough $ in the system, but there is also a complex network of investors, customers, "partner companies" and such, and all of them wants $ (or thing what they want to convert to $). We do not, for the unimaginable value what we created here, possibly in tens of billions of $, we all did it for free. The fight of the bosses is going on the value what we produced here, this fight is the important thing (for them), we not.

Comment: @peterh, I think you mistake, your two comments are not related to this post.

Answer (score 14):

The main thrust of the site is to gather high-quality answers to programming questions.  The first user fulfills this criterion by providing an answer to a basic question that - by the signal that we have - is helpful and useful.  The second user *also* fulfills the criterion so long as the signal for them answering questions remains consistent (that is to say, they may not have a big bang answer, but they have consistently well-received answers).

The less complex the rubric is, the better.  Complexity allows uncertainty or confusion to lurk in the middle of it.  The basic implication to reputation: you've either asked good questions or answered well.

That's all that's needed.